# Fast Way to Find Difference between Two Strings of Equal Length in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, string, unix

Given pairs of string like this.

```
    my $s1 = "ACTGGA";
    my $s2 = "AGTG-A";

   # Note the string can be longer than this.
```

I would like to find position and character in in `$s1` where it differs with  `$s2`.
In this case the answer would be:

```
#String Position 0-based
# First col = Base in S1
# Second col = Base in S2
# Third col = Position in S1 where they differ
C G 1
G - 4
```

I can achieve that easily with `substr()`. But it is horribly slow. 
Typically I need to compare millions of such pairs.

Is there a fast way to achieve that?

Comment: Could you post your `substr` example with a benchmark? Then we could use it as a baseline against which to compare our potential solutions. Also, these aren't Unicode strings, right? (They seem like genetic information...) Will the input always be in a narrow subset of characters (i.e. [ACTG-])?

Comment: TimToady's classic answer http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=840593: $matches = ($first ^ $second) =~ tr/\0//;

Comment: @snoopy: that gives a count of how many characters are the same, not what's wanted here

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Stringwise ^ is your friend:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $s1 = "ACTGGA";
my $s2 = "AGTG-A";

my $mask = $s1 ^ $s2;
while ($mask =~ /[^\0]/g) {
    print substr($s1,$-[0],1), ' ', substr($s2,$-[0],1), ' ', $-[0], "\n";
}
```

EXPLANATION:

The `^` (exclusive or) operator, when used on strings, returns a string composed of the result of an exclusive or on each bit of the numeric value of each character.  Breaking down an example into equivalent code:

```
"AB" ^ "ab"
( "A" ^ "a" ) . ( "B" ^ "b" )
chr( ord("A") ^ ord("a") ) . chr( ord("B") ^ ord("b") )
chr( 65 ^ 97 ) . chr( 66 ^ 98 )
chr(32) . chr(32)
" " . " "
"  "
```

The useful feature of this here is that a nul character (`"\0"`) occurs when and only when the two strings have the same character at a given position.  So `^` can be used to efficiently compare every character of the two strings in one quick operation, and the result can be searched for non-nul characters (indicating a difference).  The search can be repeated using the /g regex flag in scalar context, and the position of each character difference found using `$-[0]`, which gives the offset of the beginning of the last successful match.

Comment: Very neat example of using @-, by the way.

Comment: It'd be nice if you explained what was going on here.

Comment: thanks for the suggested edit to add an explanation, @carandraug; I've done it somewhat differently.

Comment: 9 years later, `perldoc -f ^` says `If the "bitwise" feature is enabled via "use feature 'bitwise'" or "use v5.28", then this operator always treats its operands as numbers`

Comment: @bobbogo yes, with the bitwise feature, use the explict string operator `^.` instead of `^`

Answer (score 4):

Use binary bit ops on the complete strings.

Things like `$s1 & $s2` or `$s1 ^ $s2` run incredibly fast, and work with strings of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 3):

I was bored on Thanksgiving break 2012 and answered the question and more. It will work on strings of equal length. It will work if they are not. I added a help, opt handling just for fun. I thought someone might find it useful. 
If you are new to PERL add don't know. Don't add any code in your script below **DATA** to the program.
Have fun.

./diftxt -h

```
    usage: diftxt [-v ] string1 string2
                   -v = Verbose 
                  diftxt [-V|--version]
                  diftxt [-h|--help]  "This help!"
Examples:  diftxt test text
           diftxt "This is a test" "this is real"

    Place Holders:  space = "·" , no charater = "ζ"
```

cat ./diftxt
----------- cut ✂----------

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
my %options=();
getopts("Vhv", \%options);
my $helptxt='
        usage: diftxt [-v ] string1 string2
                       -v = Verbose 
                      diftxt [-V|--version]
                      diftxt [-h|--help]  "This help!"
    Examples:  diftxt test text
               diftxt "This is a test" "this is real"

        Place Holders:  space = "·" , no charater = "ζ"';
my $Version = "inital-release 1.0 - Quincey Craig 11/21/2012";

print "$helptxt\n\n" if defined $options{h};
print "$Version\n" if defined $options{V};
if (@ARGV == 0 ) {
 if (not defined $options{h}) {usage()};
 exit;
}

my $s1 = "$ARGV[0]";
my $s2 = "$ARGV[1]";
my $mask = $s1 ^ $s2;

#  setup unicode output to STDOUT
binmode DATA, ":utf8";
my $ustring = <DATA>;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my $_DIFF = '';
my $_CHAR1 = '';
my $_CHAR2 = '';

sub usage
{
        print "\n";
        print "usage: diftxt [-v ] string1 string2\n";
        print "               -v = Verbose \n";
        print "       diftxt [-V|--version]\n";
        print "       diftxt [-h|--help]\n\n";
        exit;
}

sub main
{
 print "\nOrig\tDiff\tPos\n----\t----\t----\n" if defined $options{v};
 while ($mask =~ /[^\0]/g) {
### redirect stderr to allow for test of empty variable with error message from substr   
    open STDERR, '>/dev/null';
    if (substr($s2,$-[0],1) eq "") {$_CHAR2 = "\x{03B6}";close STDERR;} else {$_CHAR2 = substr($s2,$-[0],1)};
    if (substr($s2,$-[0],1) eq " ") {$_CHAR2 = "\x{00B7}"};
      $_CHAR1 = substr($s1,$-[0],1);
    if ($_CHAR1 eq "") {$_CHAR1 = "\x{03B6}"} else {$_CHAR1 = substr($s1,$-[0],1)};
    if ($_CHAR1 eq " ") {$_CHAR1 = "\x{00B7}"};
### Print verbose Data  
   print $_CHAR1, "\t", $_CHAR2, "\t", $+[0], "\n" if defined $options{v};
### Build difference list 
   $_DIFF = "$_DIFF$_CHAR2";
### Build mask 
   substr($s1,"$-[0]",1) = "\x{00B7}";
 } ### end loop

 print "\n" if defined $options{v};
 print "$_DIFF, ";
 print "Mask: \"$s1\"\n";
} ### end main
if ($#ARGV == 1) {main()};
__DATA__
```

Answer (score -3):

This is the easiest form you can get

```
my $s1 = "ACTGGA";
my $s2 = "AGTG-A";

my @s1 = split //,$s1;
my @s2 = split //,$s2;

my $i = 0;
foreach  (@s1) {
    if ($_ ne $s2[$i]) {
        print "$_, $s2[$i] $i\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```