# Fast Way to Find Difference between Two Unicode Strings in Perl vol 2

Tags: string, perl, unicode

In original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4709537/196241) on same topic is cool and fast [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4709643/196241), but newer perls don't support such use case anymore, they give warning of deprecation:

```
Use of strings with code points over 0xFF as arguments to bitwise xor (^) operator is deprecated
```

How to find differences between two unicode strings in Perl?

Comment: Maybe Encode them to UTF-8 octets and then XOR the octet strings?

Comment: @Corion, added encode example too

Comment: @Corion, you could submit it as answer, introduced my own bug, when got `substr outside of string at...` warnings

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, go ahead, but post it as an answer.

Comment: @ikegami, it is actually Corion's answer, I will post it as answer, but only after 24h (and if he has not submitted it)

Comment: Using UTF-8 is a no-go. For example, comparing `Éric` and `Eric` will give you 4 differences.

Comment: @ikegami, ok, that's why i got string length differences...

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah - thinking about the UTF-8 indices vs. the Unicode indices was what delayed my answer.Your solution is much nicer in that regard.

Comment: I really wish they hadn't deprecated that; it worked just fine as was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the string using a fixed-width encoding.

```
my $s1 = encode('UTF-32', $original_string_1);
my $s2 = encode('UTF-32', $original_string_2);

my $mask = $s1 ^ $s2;
while ($mask =~ /\G(?:\0{4})*+(.{4})/sg) {
    my $pos = $-[1] / 4;
    printf "%d %s %s\n",
       $pos,
       substr($original_string_1, $pos, 1),
       substr($original_string_2, $pos, 1);
}
```

Of course, this still has the problems of using XOR (has problems with insertions and deletions, as opposed to replacements). [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Diff) provides something that "resynchronizes".

Also, be wary that not all code points are suitable for printing on their own. Control characters, continuation marks, and other code points should probably not printed out directly.

Comment: does it mean, that without normalization it may give some false positives?

Comment: Integrated my comment  and my reply to yours into my answer

Comment: This will work for strings containing only Unicode characters, but not in the event that you have characters wider than 32 bits

Comment: @ysth, True, but that's what the question asks for

Answer (score 1):

Encoding the Unicode strings down to UTF-8 encoded octets should work without warnings:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode 'encode';
use charnames ':full'; # just for the example below

    binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

sub cmp_unicode {
    my ($s1, $s2) = @_;
    $s1 = encode( 'UTF-8' => $s1 );
    $s2 = encode( 'UTF-8' => $s2 );
    my $mask = $s1^$s2;
    while ($mask =~ /[^\0]/g) {
        print substr($s1,$-[0],1), ' ', substr($s2,$-[0],1), ' ', $-[0], "\n";
    }
}

cmp_unicode( 'abc', 'def' );
cmp_unicode( "   <\N{SNOWMAN}>", "   <\N{FATHER CHRISTMAS}>" );
cmp_unicode( "   <\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}!!>", "   <...>" );
```

The indices will be the indices of the octets, not the indices in the Unicode strings. @ikegami's solution of decoding to UTF-32 is much better as it finds the indices in the original Unicode strings. An adapted example is below:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode 'encode';
use charnames ':full'; # just for the example below

    binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-32)';

sub cmp_unicode {
    my ($s1, $s2) = @_;
    $s1_32 = encode( 'UTF-32' => $s1 );
    $s2_32 = encode( 'UTF-32' => $s2 );
    my $mask = $s1_32^$s2_32;
    while ($mask =~ /\G(?:\0{4})*+(.{4})/sg) {
    printf "%d %s %s\n",
       $pos,
       substr($s1, $pos, 1),
       substr($s2, $pos, 1);
    }
}

cmp_unicode( 'abc', 'def' );
cmp_unicode( "   <\N{SNOWMAN}>", "   <\N{FATHER CHRISTMAS}>" );
cmp_unicode( "   <\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}!!>", "   <...>" );
```

Whether the upgrade to 32-bit (four times the data) is still fast enough or you simply don't care about the character positions is for you to decide.

Comment: Using UTF-32 isn't about getting the position. It's because UTF-8 simply doesn't work. For example, comparing `Éric` and `Eric` give 4 differences (and prints garbage). For example, comparing the single-character strings `㙡` and `♠` give 2 differences (and prints garbage). etc

Comment: @ikegami Sure - but as long as you mostly care about the rough position of the differences, it works. You can somewhat resynchronize, but that goes bad when you have enough variable-width characters like my third example, `ä` vs `.`.

Comment: Re "*as long as you mostly care about the rough position of the differences, it works.*", The first example I gave disproves that. There's no difference anywhere the last character of the string.